# bxslider and jQuery - getCurrentSlide

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am new to jQuery and javascript and have been unable to resolve the following bxslider issue.

I would like to be able to change the css attributes of various elements based on the slider position.

I have looked at the getCurrentSlide method in the bxslider documentation but using the following I always get var current == 0.

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
var current = slider.getCurrentSlide();
```

What should I do in order for the current variable to be equal to the index value of the current slide and for the index value to update every time the slide position changes? My bxslider contains 4 slides.

-- Thanks.

Comment: Please don't just ask a question and then leave. If a solution helped you, check it correct. If not, please give more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're putting the `getCurrentSlide()` method in the `document.ready` call. On load, the current slide will always be 0 because it's an array that's 0-indexed. If you look at the [callback api](http://bxslider.com/examples/callback-api), you can use the `onSlideAfter` method to update the `current` variable. A simple implementation of that would look like this:

```
var current = 0;
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  onSliderLoad: function(){
    // do funky JS stuff here
    alert('Slider has finished loading. Click OK to continue!');
  },
  onSlideAfter: function(){
    // increment current by 1 each time this method is called
    current += 1;
  }
});
```